# Conditional Formatting Non Contiguous Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, range

I have a large spreadsheet, which came prepopulated with data. What I would like to do is the following. If I select I7:15, and apply this conditional formatting

Cell Value is equal to =G7, colour cell orange

Then as expected  I8's format is =G8, I9's is =G9 etc.

But, if I select the I7:15 and I19:30 and apply the same formatting above, it does not work. I1's is **GG65531**.

**My question is this:** how can I apply this conditional formatting to non contiguous ranges? I have several ranges which need the same formatting applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the formatting to the first range and then use the **format painter** to apply it to other ranges

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure and I can't test but I think if you apply the formatting to the first range and select the others and do a redo it will work.